# Is it possible to restrict using IDs already used on a different layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geopackage, vector-layer

I am working on a rather complex data model for a GIS-project in QGIS 3.16.3. The entire data model is stored in one single geopackage. Different layers are used to represent different geometry types where necessary (e.g. buildings as polygons but moveable items as points). So far, I have not found a solution that would allow to store all wanted features/geometries in one layer.

**Problem:** Each feature get's an alphanumeric ID that has to be unique over the entiry project. For each layer the ID can be easily be set to be unique. However, that does not prevent the user from using the same ID once on the point layer and once on the polygon layer.

The current working state of the point layer's attribute table would look like this (further fields are to be added, the polygon layer has the same attribute structure):
[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to expand the unique-constraint to check against a field of another layer?

**First Idea for a solution:** I could use an automatically generated UUID as the primary key, but the specification sheet asks for a human readable identifier, at least in addition to a UUID. It would be possible to use the UUID to link to an additional table holding the human readable IDs for the entire project, but this solution seems inefficient to me.

**Edit**: The ID is supposed to be human readable as well as logical and modular, which means: an entire building may get the ID *B1* while its first floor would get the ID *B1.1*, the second room on this floor *B1.1.2* and so forth. This system is supposed to ease orientation for the user. I am not sure, however, if this is an intelligent way of designing an ID.

Comment: You may include a code for geometry type or layer name as part of the ID, so for a  initially duplicated "B1"  you will rather get something like "POLYGON_B1" and "POINT_B1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add this expression in the `"ID"` field of each layer:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN COUNT($id) <> 0 THEN (CONCAT('layer_name', COUNT($id)+1))
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tryed it with a sample dataset, which did not work as intended. Would the "ID" fields have to be connected with a relationship for this to work? I also editet the question, since the IDs are specified to be more complex than emphasized in the original question, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have some fields that differentiate if it's an entire building, a floor, a room an so on ? Could you provide a sample of your attribute table in your question ?

Comment: So far I don't have such a field. I have a fields for "type" and "subtype" as a value map and a value relation widgets. I could either add room, floor etc. as subtypes or add an additional field for this information.

Comment: Edited the original question with an overview of the fields of one layer.

Comment: Since you don't have a field named "id" you shall replace "$id" in my answer by "fid". Then you shall improve this expression by using a conditional statement based on two fields giving information about the type and subtype of your polygon (floor, room) and so on

Comment: Thanks again. It requires a lot of tweaking to match all cases and has some shortfalls (e.g. COUNT("fid")+1 can lead to jumps in the the list of identifiers), but it is by far better than leaving the field a free text field.